# Editor in eclipse has vanished

Tags: eclipse

I feel slightly like n00b encountering windows for the first time, but I have lost the editor window in Eclipse. I had dragged one of two tabs to one side such that I could view the two files side by side and it disappeared. Foolishly, I then dragged the remaining tab to the same position and found that it also disappeared.
When I select 'Windows' > 'Navigation' > 'Next editor' I can see that both files are still open. I have tried opening other files, and although they do open they are similarly invisible. I tried resetting the perspective, but the editor was left absent. I'm running out of ideas, so any contributions would be highly welcome! I'm using a mac by the way.

Comment: Try Window -> New Editor

Comment: I ended up using cmd-W to close the editors one by one, then was able to open a new editor. Many thanks for the suggestions though!

Comment: In my case "New Editor" did open a new editor but still invisible. Tried "New window" there all my open editor were visible again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just so this case be changed to 'answered':
I ended up using cmd-W to close the editors one by one, then was able to open a new editor. I still don't understand what caused the problem, but at least it is solved now. Many thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 32):

Perspective reset or window->new editor did not work for me. What worked though was to create a new window with Window->New Window, and then close the first one with editor hidden. Hope this help.

Comment: Worked with Code Composer Studio (which is based on Eclipse). It's sad that this is necessary, but thanks.

Comment: @krs013 Yes, very sad. Just another reason to give up on Code Composer Studio. http://www.electronvector.com/blog/escape-your-embedded-vendors-ide.

Answer (score 4):

Pressing the **F12** key normally focuses the Editor only if the Editor is not minimized.

Window -> New Editor is also disabled once the Editor view is minimized.

What's definitely going to work is resetting the perspective by doing `Window -> Reset Perspective`. That should bring the editor back into view.

Take a look at **[this](http://youtu.be/-qm70Vq7y3M)** screencast which shows how to do this.

Comment: Resetting perspective did not bring back a vanished editor. Opening a new window and ditching the original one did.

Answer (score 1):

They might have been in a separate window. Try right clicking on the Eclipse icon on your dock and see if the editors are there. If yes, drag them to your IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem today. I solved it just by `Window > Reset perspective...`

Answer (score 0):

I have lost the editor too doing drag & drop. I try all here, and finally I used Window > New Widow and the second one comes with editor.